# Development of a password manager as Chrome extension

Tags: security, google-chrome-extensions

I want to start developing a passowrd manager as Chrome extension and I am really devastated and confusused. I search the internet and can't find a clear pass to reach it. I am kindly asking for your help and guidance. I think if you can help me with the developing of a simple one, I can continue to improve myself. For example do you know any simple open source extension and well documented one? I am familiar with programming languages such as C++ and pythons.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... do you know any simple open source extension and well documented one?

There are numerous open source password managers for Chrome.

Just browse through [this list of repositories](https://github.com/search?q=password%20manager%20chrome) in *GitHub*, and you will be able to see the codes there.

Most of them are written in JavaScript, as you see in the left-side menu of the link.

Comment: Are they documented in a way that I can understand? For learning purposes? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, so you are looking for a step-by-step tutorial on how to create a password manager for Chrome? Hm, I am not sure I can find one so easily. - You should probably learn some basics on JavaScript, then try to understand the relevant GitHub repositories by looking at their codes; many of them are well-commented.

Comment: Ok thank you so much